# Layout problem with autogenerated DataGrid in WPF/XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I've got a problem with WPF/XAML. I can't figure out how to let the left Grid (with a centered image inside and backgroud color) grow its height, depending on the autogenerated height on the datagrid on the right.

They both are presented in a global grid. If I set a fixed height on the corresponding row, the autogenerated datagrid shows a cruel vertical line, depending on the fixed row-height I set before.

[layout with row-height on auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjjDq.png)

[layout with fixed row-height, but with ugly line at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiYyj.png)

```
<!--ElementR0C1-->
<Grid Name="test">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Width ElementsC1-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--START-->
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource L1}" VerticalAlignment="Top">Process</Label>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="DDDDDD">
        <Image Margin="0,30,0,0" Height="64" Width="64" Source="../../Resources/ok.png" Name="imgJobs" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grdJobs" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="500">
-- some stuff here
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please, share your xaml code

Comment: I think that the main point of confusion here might be that your left grid is bigger than the one on the right.
the margin + height of the image give it a height of 94.

Comment: @YotamS. the datagrid on the right is growing bigger than the grid on the the left.

Comment: I believe reducing the margin will cause the left button to be higher up on #1 (if that is what you are trying to accomplish).
You can set a MinHight on the DataGrid to make sure #2 does not happen.
The height on the left Grid is already growing automatically, as Grid's default behavior is to stretch to fill.

Comment: you can see the result in pic#1. the left grid does not go up with the auto generated high from the right grid. i want the left grid to fill the complete space with its background (gray) and the inner image to be more centered thoughout the whole height